# Architecture idea

Tags: configuration

I'm a beginner in SFDC app development, I need to integrate my apex code with R/python. Explain me how the architecture should be, where i have to host it (whether my own server or sfdc has the facility to host) or any better idea.

Comment: It is unclear what you mean to do. Are you asking if you want to run your R/python code in the Salesforce container, or if you want to have your R/python code access the Salesforce services and data?

Answer (score 5):

Salesforce only runs its proprietary language and stack. You can't introduce other languages or components.

Salesforce own Heroku that supports [multiple languages](https://devcenter.heroku.com/categories/language-support) including Python and has Salesforce integration features such as [Heroku Connect](https://www.heroku.com/connect) but at a fairly high price. I also note there is this project https://github.com/virtualstaticvoid/heroku-buildpack-r.

Or you can host your R/python code in some other cloud service and connect to Salesforce via web service calls.

You say "integrate my apex code", but working in other programming languages you can really only make web service calls to Salesforce, to either access the raw data (the SObjects) or to access custom web service APIs that you create in Apex that expose your Apex code.

Comment: Also, Canvas API.

Comment: @Peter As someone who has never used that, perhaps a separate answer to explain how it fits in?